# How to Fix Right Click Menu Randomly Popping Up on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm using HP laptop with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, Now day's I can't use the system as it's continuously showing mouse right click popup window, I don't know how to resolve this issue, please help me to solve this.

Comment: Have you confirmed the laptop isn't detecting a right click event over & over (ie. hardware issue?)  Have you looked at `xev` or otherwise to see if there's a reason for the 'event',  ie. I'd open a terminal, run `xev` and see if events such as keyboard/mouse-clicks are occurring thus isn't not a desktop config issue, but stuck right-mouse-button or the like.

Comment: I just start having this same issue. It could be my KVM switch. It is new behavior though. Logical to conclude something might have changed on the software side of the fence.

Comment: OK tried xev and I am seeing spurious events generated but this is not a problem on the same hardware using Mac or Windows.

Comment: Well for the short term, switching mice seems to fix. We'll see if I still believe that in an hour or two.